# how to pass parameters to Powershell script and run it on a remote computer

Tags: powershell, remote-execution

I am trying to pass 2 parameters to a PS script which will patch the SQL Server on a remote machine. Here is the code i used :

```
$Patcher = "\\remoteShareLocation\SQLpatcher.ps1"
$ver = "SQL2012"
$inst = "NEWINST"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName RMTMACHINE -credential dmn\usrname -ScriptBlock {$Patcher $ver $inst}
```

This asks for credentials but doesn't run and show any output also. Anything wrong with syntax ? Any alternate cmdlet please ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you have powershell V3 or higher you can use the `using` prefix to "transmit" the local vars to remote host :

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName RMTMACHINE -credential $cred -ScriptBlock {$using:Patcher $using:ver $using:inst}
```

for olders versions look at the `-argumentlist` parameter of [invoke-command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx)

Comment: Just to complement: If $Patcher, $ver and $inst are commands then you have to put "&" before that. Ex.: Invoke-Command -ComputerName RMTMACHINE -credential $cred -ScriptBlock { & $using:Patcher $using:ver $using:inst}

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$cred = Get-Credential
Invoke-Command -ComputerName RMTMACHINE -credential $cred -ScriptBlock {$Patcher $ver $inst}
```

or create a credential object like this:

```
$username = "username"
$password = "password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)
```

You'll need to pass a credential object instead of Domain\username.

And to run a script file remotely please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/10446318/4550393

Comment: Did not work with credentials also, so tried sending parameters :   $ScriptBlockContent = { 
     param ($p, $v, $i)
     powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass $p $v $i }

 Invoke-Command -ComputerName RMTMACHINE -credential $cred -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlockContent -ArgumentList $Patcher, $ver, $inst.   This also throws error saying : The term '\\remoteShareLocation\Patcher.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,verify that the path is correct and try again.